# java.nio.file.InvalidPathException in java-llama.cpp

Tags: eclipse, llama

English is not my native language, I come from Germany.

I have downloaded https://github.com/kherud/java-llama.cpp to Eclipse via git, the build goes through so far, but later there is a java.nio.file.InvalidPathException.

```
 -> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at examples.MainExample.main(MainExample.java:19)
Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <"> at index 0: "D:\DEV\64\java\oracle\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\llama.dll
```

I tried to debug this, but I can't find the place where it uses this path. I have already set the jdk 21 for the project, 1.8.0 is also available, I have now copied the dll into the folder.

However, it should not use this path at all.

The code is:

```
public class MainExample {

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println(args);
        
        LlamaModel.setLogger((level, message) -> System.out.print(message));
        ...
    }
```

And then in `LlamaModel.java`

```
public static native void setLogger(@Nullable BiConsumer<LogLevel, String> callback);
```

There it already exits, I can't find the place with the path in the debugger.
Does anyone have an idea how I can find the error?

Manuel

Comment: It is unclear what you did. Where did you get the `llama.dll` (from which build and which variant)? What makes you say _"the build goes through so far"_ (which build did you execute with what result exactly)? The stack trace refers to line 19 of `examples.MainExample`, but the code you showed [differs from the original](https://github.com/kherud/java-llama.cpp/blob/643dc4f079ca07d8d096410e486bf4b3d5abfc1d/src/test/java/examples/MainExample.java#L19). Did you run `examples.MainExample` via Maven or as Java application? With which arguments and with which model?

Comment: `examples.MainExample` works for me using the [JAR from Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.kherud/llama/2.3.1) with [TinyLlama](https://huggingface.co/TinyLlama/tinyLlama-intermediate-checkpoints-after-1T-token/tree/main) which I converted myself to GGUF and quantized as Q4_K_M. The JAR does not contain `de.kherud.llama.ModelResolver` so I set the `modelPath` directly to something like `String modelPath = "C:\\...\\models\\TinyLlama.Q4_K.gguf";`. When running with an older OpenJ9 Java VM, I also need to remove `.setNGpuLayers(43)` which was not needed with a HotSpot Java VM.